# What is the dimension of a tangent space?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives, surfaces

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be open and $f: U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be an immersion (so that $U$ and $f(U)$ are diffeomorphic).

Let $p \in U$. Thus $f(p)$ is a point on the surface $f(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

**Then which of the following is correct?**

> ***1.*** $\dim T_p U = 2$.
>
> **2.** $\dim T_{f(p)} f(U) = 2$.
>
> **3.** $\dim T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}^3 = 3$.
>
> **4.** $T_{f(p)}f(U) \subset T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}^3$.
>
> **5.** The surface normal $N(p)$ is *always* an element of $T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R}^3$ but *never* an element of $T_{f(p)}f(U)$.
>
> **6.** If $v \in T_p U$, then $v$ is of the form $(p, (v_1, v_2))$.
>
> **7.** If $v \in T_{f(p)} f(U)$ then $v$ is of the form $(f(p), (v_1, v_2, 0))$ and thus $T_p U \simeq T_{f(p)} f(U)$.
>
> **8.** If $w \in \left[T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus T_{f(p)}f(U)\right]$ then it can *not* be identified with a $v \in T_p U$.
>
> **9.** $d_p f: T_p U \to T_{f(p)}\mathbb{R^3}$ (in particular, it does *not* map inside of $T_{f(p)}f(U)$ which is 2, not 3, dimensional) can be identified with a $3 \times 2$ matrix (as opposed to a $2 \times 2$ matrix).

I am using this to try to learn about the shape operator.

Comment: I suggest you use numbers instead of bullets.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Done. Hopefully this makes it easier to read.

Comment: Um, aren't there more than one answers...? I mean if $U$ and $f(U)$ are diffeomorphic, 2 and 1 has to be the same. And 4 is true by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer to your items by number in the order in which they do occur, so if you change the order it will become wrong.

Some of these look ill-posed to me. Especially the last one. While $d_pf$ can in fact be identified with a $3\times 2 $ matrix, it *does* map the source into $T_{f(p)} f(U)$ which can be identified with a subspace of $T_{f(p)} \mathbb{R}^3$ (so the remark starting with 'in particular' is incorrect). Depending on the representation chosen it can *also* be represented by a $2\times 2$ matrix (with respect to a choice of base vector fields on both $T_p(U)$ and $T_{f(p)} f(U)$, at least locally.

Also note that an immersion may have a self-intersecting image. You can only locally claim that it is diffeomorphism on the image. Assuming you *know* it is a global diffeomorphism some of your question are a bit easier to respond to (I will assume this is the case).

Then 
1) - 6) are true, 7) is not, assuming you are using the standard Euclidean Coordinate system in the target space. (it can be of the form $(f(p), (v_1, v_2, v_3))$. 8) is correct again, if, by 'identify' you mean by means of $d_pf$.
9) I already discussed.

I would rephrase 6) as 'can be expressed in the form'

Regarding the follow up queustion in the comment: *locally* you can choose a unit normal vector field along the surface. With $f$ and the normal vector field you can define coordinates in the neighbourhood of $f(U)$ (you may have to make $U$ smaller for this to work) in which $f(U)$ is represented by $x_3=0$ -- you just use the signed normal distance to $f(U)$ as third coordinate and the image of the coordinates in $U\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, $(\bar x_1, \bar x_2)$ under $f$ as the first two coordinates $(x_1,x_3)$ in the image. That this is in fact a coordinate system follows from the implicit function theorem after some calculations (you may try to search for 'normal' coordinates).

Comment: Thank you so much! It is a huge relief for me to have this question answered. One follow-up: just to confirm, the fact that $f$ is an immersion means that $df$ is of rank $2$, so we can always choose coordinates such that one of the rows becomes identically zero (which I think is the content of the local immersion theorem), and the remaining two rows can be identified with a $2 \times 2$ matrix, which is then invertible?  Otherwise I am not sure I quite understand what you are saying when you state that it can be represented by both a $3 \times 2$ matrix and a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: Also thank you for correcting my misconceptions about immersions -- one example I should have remembered of a self-intersecting immersion is Boy's surface, which maps the real projective plane into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: @William I edited the answer to include a reply to your follow up question.

Comment: Are the $x_i$ the coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$? And do you mean $x_3=0$? or $f(x_3)=0$?

Comment: @William As an additional advice (addressing the 'relieved to have the question answered'): consider asking single questions in one posting and explaining what the background of your question is, by giving a reason why you asked the question. Your chances to get an answer at all will increase, and you chances to get an explanation along with the answer (instead of just yes/no) will increase, as weill. Avoid follow up questions by commment, rather ask a new question. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @William another edit will make the $x_3$ question a bit clearer (I hope)